# Option --square for camera calibration with circle/acircle pattern

Tags: calibration, ros-melodic, ros-kinetic, image-pipeline, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a question regarding the camera_calibration package. In the documentation (http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration) it is mentioned that it is possible to use a circular / asymmetric circular calibration pattern. However, there are no further information about how to set the parameter --square. Should it be the spacing between circles or the diameter (radius?) of an individual circle?

Thanks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327669/option---square-for-camera-calibration-with-circle/acircle-pattern/) by [astero](https://answers.ros.org/users/43909/astero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Calibration patterns work because they have clear features which can be precisely located, the corner of a squares in the case of a checker board or the centre of circles in the case of the circular pattern. In both cases the spacing is the distance between these features.

In the case of the circular pattern you need to specify the distance between the centres of the circles. ROS uses OpenCV to perform the vision processing for this, which is [described here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html).

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1